# Normal on the surface of a unit sphere with alternate norm

Tags: geometry

How would one go about computing the surface normal at a point $p = (x, y, z)$ on the unit sphere defined by $1=x^k+y^k+z^k$, given that $k$ can take any positive real value?  If it is simpler, how could it be computed for just $k>=2$?

Comment: How can you guarantee that it will be a sphere? I mean is there any proof?

Comment: Hint: Show that this shape can be projected onto one of the axes let's say $z$ such that exists $f$ such that $z=f(x,y)$  for all points on the shape and then use the equation for the tangent surface to find the normal.

Comment: @Qwerty this is the *definition* of a sphere with respect to the new norm.  Of course, this won't be the usual (i.e. Euclidean) sphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well known that for any surface given by an equation of the form
$$
f(x,y,z) = 0
$$
where $f$ is differentiable, the vector of partial derivatives $(f_x(p),f_y(p),f_z(p))$ is normal to the surface at the point $p$.

In this case, we may thereby compute that the surface normal vector at $p = (x,y,z)$ is
$$
k(x^{k-1},y^{k-1},z^{k-1})
$$
so long as all exponentiation here is well defined as a real-valued function.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!  I've verified the result with a [desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4ann7jf12i), the normal appears to move correctly as the shape changes.